# Why LibSvm accuracy not going above 50%?

Tags: java, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, libsvm

I have news data and i want to do sentimental analysis with help of LibSVM    followed all the methods for creating training file and testing file. 
Initially started with 100 feeds data for positive and negative and test with 10 feeds test data and got above 70% of accuracy, but when i increase the size of training data i.e about 800 each and test with 100 feeds my accuracy drop to 50.999%. I don't what the reason behind this.

```
   Training
```

java -classpath libsvm.jar svm_train trainexam.train  d.model -K 1 -C 512

```
   Prediction
```

java -classpath libsvm.jar svm_predict testexam.test d.model out.txt

Result : 50.0%

```
   Training File ( -1 -> Negative , +1 -> Positive)
```

-1 1:1 2:1 3:1 4:1 5:1 6:1 7:1 8:1 9:1 10:1 11:1 12:1 13:1 14:1 15:1 16:1 17:1 18:1 19:1 20:1 21:1 22:1 17:1 23:1 24:1 17:1 25:1 26:1 27:1 28:1 29:1 30:1 17:1 31:1 30:1 17:1 32:1 26:1 17:1 6:1 17:1 33:1 26:1 17:1 5:1 6:1 34:1 35:1 36:1 17:1 37:1 22:1 30:1 38:1 39:1 40:1 41:1 19:1 20:1 42:1 43:1 44:1 45:1 46:1 40:1 47:1 48:1 49:1 27:1 28:1 50:1 17:1 23:1 16:1 51:1 25:1 52:1 53:1 54:1 55:1 17:1 56:1 57:1 58:1 17:1 59:1 57:1 60:1 10:1 11:1 12:1 61:1 62:1 8:1 30:1 17:1 6:1 30:1 14:1 59:1 
-1 63:1 64:1 65:1 66:1 67:1 30:1 68:1 69:1 70:1 71:1 40:1 72:1 73:1 74:1 75:1 76:1 51:1 77:1 78:1 79:1 80:1 81:1 52:1 82:1 17:1 83:1 26:1 79:1 84:1 85:1 73:1 86:1 87:1 88:1 89:1 90:1 91:1 30:1 17:1 22:1 92:1 26:1 17:1 93:1 94:1 95:1 96:1 97:1 98:1 90:1 99:1 100:1 17:1 101:1 77:1 102:1 78:1 17:1 81:1 103:1 104:1 105:1 106:1 107:1 108:1 78:1 109:1 110:1 51:1 111:1 30:1 112:1 113:1 30:1 114:1 115:1 116:1 90:1 117:1 118:1 119:1 120:1 17:1 121:1 75:1 70:1 122:1 40:1 123:1 124:1 125:1 126:1 17:1 109:1 127:1 128:1 129:1 130:1 131:1 30:1 51:1 132:1 26:1 87:1 86:1 133:1 134:1 135:1 17:1 81:1 136:1 104:1 137:1 138:1 17:1 90:1 139:1 140:1 141:1 142:1 143:1 17:1 86:1 144:1 145:1 17:1 101:1 77:1 146:1 107:1 147:1 30:1 17:1 148:1 40:1 149:1 150:1 78:1 151:1 152:1 153:1 154:1 17:1 155:1 70:1 156:1 95:1 92:1 90:1 157:1 40:1 92:1 94:1 78:1 17:1 113:1 158:1 104:1 40:1 70:1 159:1 16:1 59:1 160:1 161:1 162:1 17:1 121:1 124:1 62:1 71:1 40:1 163:1 164:1 165:1 76:1 119:1 166:1 86:1 57:1 17:1 167:1 26:1 17:1 168:1 90:1 169:1 26:1 170:1 79:1 171:1 73:1 17:1 101:1 172:1 173:1 174:1 175:1 17:1 121:1 70:1 176:1 17:1 169:1 167:1 30:1 112:1 177:1 178:1 179:1 180:1 181:1 26:1 17:1 116:1 182:1 63:1 7:1 183:1 62:1 184:1 185:1 186:1 135:1 17:1 187:1 188:1 189:1 190:1

```
     +1 17736:1 1218:1 485:1 4:1 79:1 17737:1 259:1 75:1 367:1 135:1 16795:1 14945:1 40:1 4444:1 2580:1 895:1 40:1 75:1 312:1 698:1 5148:1 30:1 533:1 895:1 652:1 310:1 17:1 1588:1 6890:1 73:1 97:1 79:1 1359:1 5227:1 1747:1 17738:1 17739:1 17740:1 75:1 201:1 214:1 17741:1 17742:1 17743:1 129:1 12268:1 533:1 1793:1 17744:1 30:1 17:1 2551:1 113:1 26:1 2678:1 17745:1 17746:1 17747:1 989:1 17:1 171:1 30:1 17:1 1744:1 17
```

Comment: full training file can be shared

Comment: Your data is not in proper libSVM format. Have you used the validation tool?

Comment: No. Can you please name that tool.

Comment: See libSVM FAQ: [Is there a program to check if my data are in the correct format?](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f305)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libSVM format specifies that attributes *must* be listed in ascending order.

I guess it fails to compute the kernel because the input data is not formatted correctly.

Comment: I got 68.5% accuracy while using Weka i got 79.8% accuracy.

Comment: Try normalizing your data. Weka often does implicit data normalization.

Comment: Scaled my data but that was very bad experience accuracy drop to 50.2%.

Comment: Did you apply the exact same scaling (parameters; not method! min and max may be different!) to your validation data? As you can see, SVM *can* be sensitive to normalization...

Comment: i scalled with upper limit 1 and low limit -1 (using libsvm scale)

Comment: The problem is that you may have scaled the training and the test data *independently* which must not happen. You must scale the training data, then apply the exact same scaling (i.e. save the scaling coefficients!) to the test data! (Don't include training data in scaling to avoid overfitting).